Conditional probability: could we get $P(XY \ge K|{\sigma(X)}) \le \frac{X}{K}$ by $P(Y \ge K) \le \frac{1}{K}$?
Set probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$, $\sigma$-algebra ${\mathcal V}\subset{\mathcal F} $ such that:

$X$ and $Y$ be positive random variables
for arbitrary $K > 0$, $P(Y \ge K) \le \frac{1}{K}$
$X$ is ${\mathcal V}$-measurable
$X \ge 1$ (if needed)

Can we deduce that $P(XY \ge K|{\mathcal V}) \le \frac{X}{K}$ P-a.s?
Such question seems to be clear, provided that we know all infomation about X, thus consider $P(XY \ge K|{\mathcal V})$ to be $P(Y \ge \frac{K}{X}|{\mathcal V})$. but could it be strictly proven?
@stochasticboy321 point out that such statement is wrong. How about we change select $\mathcal V$ as $\sigma(X)$?
Can we deduce that $P(XY \ge K|\sigma(X)) \le \frac{X}{K}$ P-a.s ?

Do you mean $X/K$ rather than $1/KX$? Otherwise take the constant random variable $X = 2$. You further need some assumptions on how $\mathcal{V}$ interacts with $Y$, because otherwise take $X = 2$ and $\mathcal{V} = \sigma(Y),$ in which case this conditional prob. is either $0$ or $1$ (and so not $\le X/K$ in general).

You are right, how about we modify $\mathcal V$ as $\sigma (X)$? Like markov property.

Wouldn't really be enough, e.g., if $X = Y$ almost surely. Ultimately the issue boils down to the fact that even if $P(Y \ge K)$ is small, there will be events given which $Y \ge K$ with a large chance, and one can cook up sigma algebrae that contain these events, and make $X$ measurable w.r.t. this (for instance, $X = \mathbf{1}{Y \ge K}$).  Of course, if $Y$ is independent of $\sigma(X),$ the bound does hold. In complete generality, I don't know if a softer condition is possible.

Suppose joint probabilities are given by:



$X$
$Y=0.1$
$Y=10$
$P_X$




1
0.9
0.01
0.91


2
0.03
0.06
0.09


$P_Y$
0.93
0.07
1



We have $\mathbb{E}(Y)=0.93\times0.1+0.07\times10=0.093+0.7=0.793<1$. Thus by Markov inequality, $$P(Y\geq K)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(Y)}K = \frac{0.793}{K}<\frac1{K}.$$
But for $K=20$, $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left.Y\geq \frac{K}{X}\right\rvert X=2\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Y=10\mid X=2\right)=\frac{0.06}{0.09}=\frac{2}{3} > \frac{2}{K}.$$
For the wanted inequality, I think we need $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)$ as an extra factor on the RHS.

What if we set $E(Y|X)=X$ P-a.s ?

@shanlilinghuo Then, the RHS will become $\frac{X^2}{K}$ from Markov ineq, and you might need $0<X \leq 1$.

Thanks, do you mean that? : by use conditional markov inequality $P(Y \le \frac{K}{X}|{\mathcal V}) \le \frac{XE(Y|{\mathcal V})}{K}$ since $X$ is ${\mathcal V}$-mesurable

yes, that's what I meant.
